# How does HTML5 determine which window a link, with a target name, should render into?

Tags: html, hyperlink

```
<a href="http://www.google.com/" target="pagename">Link</a>
```

This somewhat does what I expect: When I click the link, it opens a new tab to Google, and when I click it again, it renders again in the same new tab.

However, when I open a second version of a page with the same target, I don't get directed to the Google tab already open.

https://jsfiddle.net/2jc7fdvr/

ex: Open the jsfiddle into two tabs, click each, and get two tabs with Google.

In the console for both Google pages, window.name comes back the same, so how does each page determine its target?

Comment: I don't know why you are wondering that but I think your browser assign another identifier (hidden to you) to your opened tab. Also `target` can be used with frames like this : https://jsfiddle.net/2jc7fdvr/1/

Comment: Another funny fact with your example is that if you open `another jsfiddle` into your `opened tab`, clicking on the new fiddle opens another tab, but clicking on the previous one replaces the 2nd fiddle by your url.